# How do I use multiple entries with Zend_Config_Xml?

Tags: xml, zend-framework, zend-config-xml, multiple-entries

I am trying to use multiple entries with Zend_Config_XML, but no luck so far. I have the following structure.

```
<acl>
<admin>
    <access moudle="module1" controller="controller1" action="action1">
    <access moudle="module2" controller="controller2" action="action2">
    <access moudle="module3" controller="controller3" action="action3">
</admin>
<manager>
    <access moudle="module1" controller="controller1" action="action1">
    <access moudle="module2" controller="controller2" action="action2">
    <access moudle="module3" controller="controller3" action="action3">
</manager>
</acl>
```

I can't even access to access entries.

Should I use other XML classes to use multiple entries?

Comment: Where's the structure? A little more info..

Answer (score 1):

I've never used XML configs with ZF but it looks like you have a typo in your XML - the attribute name should be module, not moudle.

Comment: It does not matter actually. "moudle" is just an attribute. it can be anything. My question is that ZF does not parse it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that is not valid XML. You need to close the access tag:

```
<access moudle="module1" controller="controller1" action="action1" />
```

And as the other guy who's name I can't remember said, you have a typo in moudle.

Comment: Works fine for me:

fran@frarch:~/test$ php test.php 
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["moudle"]=>
    string(7) "module1"
    ["controller"]=>
    string(11) "controller1"
    ["action"]=>
    string(7) "action1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["moudle"]=>
    string(7) "module2"
    ["controller"]=>
    string(11) "controller2"
    ["action"]=>
    string(7) "action2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["moudle"]=>
    string(7) "module3"
    ["controller"]=>
    string(11) "controller3"
    ["action"]=>
    string(7) "action3"
  }
}